Setting AUTH_USER_MODEL for user app within a v1 folder
My django project structure looks like this
/api
  manage.py
  poetry.lock
  /api
    /v1
      __init__.py
      /users
        __init__.py
        models.py 
        ...
      /properties
        __init__.py
        ...

I'm trying to set up a custom User model by setting AUTH_USER_MODEL within settings.py.
However, I'm getting this error
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'user.User' that has not been installed

I've tried values
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "api.v1.user.User"
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "v1.user.User"
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user.User"

But none of them fixed the issue
I also have these INSTALLED_APPS
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "api.v1.users",
    "api.v1.reservations",
    "api.v1.properties",
]

and my User model currently looks like this
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


Have you tried users.User as you app is called users?

@Marco ugh.... missed that..... Thanks for the extra pair of eyes. Much appreciated

@Marco Feel free to add a reply and I can accept the answer!

You need to set users.User as described in the Django documentation:

This dotted pair describes the label of the Django app (which must be
in your INSTALLED_APPS), and the name of the Django model that you
wish to use as your user model.

